# Web API windows authentication along with SSL

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api which is configured to use windows authentication since, I need to capture the current user in the web api I am using the following statement to capture it.

```
string user = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
```

Above line doesn't capture user instead it captures DOMAIN\machineName$, which is I believe is coming from the client SSL certificate since, I am using domain issued cert for specific machine as client cert.

The client call is as below.

```
using (WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler())
{
    handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(this.cert);
    handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += CertificateValidator.CertificateValidationCallback;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test-VM/Request/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/CreateRequest", request))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                 return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<long>();
            }
            else
            {
                 throw new HttpRequestException(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping if I set the UserDefaultCredentials property to true it would serve the purpose but, looks like it is been overwritten by the certificate.

Is there a way to capture the caller username while using the SSL?

Comment: Try this:  string user =  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

Comment: I tried it but, it renders the same DOMAIN\machineName$. It's like a network service or something. I did use windows authentication in the past and there I used HttpClientHandler instead of WebRequestHandler. I am using later here since, I can load the client certificate easily. I doubt, there maybe something wrong in the client.

Comment: `WebRequestHandler`, as you might already realise, is a descendent of `HttpClientHandler`. Per the [UseDefaultCredentials documentation], (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx), have you instead tried to "set the Credentials property to the credentials of the client on whose behalf the request is made"? I'd ideally take a look at the source code for `WebRequestHandler` to find out what it's doing under the covers, but am struggling to find it...

Comment: `WebRequestHandler` works fine if I remove SSL so, there is nothing wrong with the class but, looks like once I add the client certificate to the handler it erases the default credential or certificate has higher priority than the default credentials. Looks like in this case I require multiple authentication but, just don't know how to handle this situation.